# Get hostName and Instance Id of the current ec2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to get instanceId and hostname of the ec2 instance from where the application running.

I have used the following

```
String instanceId = EC2MetadataUtils.getInstanceId();

String HostName = EC2MetadataUtils.getLocalHostName();
```

But these two values are different from the actual ec2 info, which is showing in the AWS instance window.

Comment: What is different? Show the actual values that you are getting and expecting.

Comment: AWS instance ID showing as 02de3...when i execute the code in java I am getting like this  082853...

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: You are trying to mask the very data I am trying to see.

Comment: String instanceId = EC2MetadataUtils.getInstanceId(); this is working.. I compared with wrong instance id.. But the hostName is still getting wrong.